What is the intention of the following words that appear in C11?
C11：6.5.2.2 p9:

If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the
expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is
undefined.

As far as I know,The behavior of the function call expression depends on whether the prototype of the function being called is in scope at the point of call.
Then for "the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function", doesn't the type pointed to by the expression of the called function just be the function type, that is, the function declaration?
To be frank, in my opinion, isn't the intention of the standard just that "function declarations should be compatible with definitions"?
And, 6.2.7 p2 has already mentioned:

All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Then does this mean that 6.5.2.2 p9 is redundant?, or maybe there is a problem with my understanding?
Thank you for your reading and answering.

Pointers to functions should have the right type. Also, if the function is called with incorrect types and there is either no prototype in scope or the prototype in scope doesn't match the function definition, you get undefined behaviour.

I agree with @JonathanLeffler but doesn't POSIX dlsym require the ability to cast void * to a function pointer of arbitrary type?

The C Standard does not require pointers to objects (e.g. void * or int *) to be convertible to a pointer to function or vice versa.  POSIX’s dlsym() does require convertibility between pointers to objects (void *) and pointers to functions.  The wording on that changed between POSIX 2008 and the current version.  In practice, the main problem is getting the compiler to shut up about such conversions.

POSIX defines a number of behaviors that are undefined in pure standard C. That's just one of them.

@JonathanLeffler Do happen to know what changed from 2008 to 2024?  Or have deep link handy for the current posix section?

@AllanWind — this comment of mine contains the information I was looking for.  Also related — another comment of mine.

@JonathanLeffler Thanks for digging it up for me.  I appreciate it.

Section 6.5.2.2 deals with function calls, which is the context of the above quote.  The compatibility of declarations is covered elsewhere.
Paragraph 9 in particular deals with the expression used to call a function.  This could be a simple declaration or a function pointer.  For example:
int foo(char *p)
{
    // do something with p
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    void (*fp)(void) = (void (*)(void))foo;
    fp();
    return 0;
}

The function call fp is undefined behavior as per 6.5.2.2p9 because the function foo is being called through an incompatible function pointer type.

How many UBs are in this code: https://godbolt.org/z/Y4v7bTMbr
